# How to search a file for all positions within a range in perl or python?

Tags: python, perl

Ok, so I'm new to this, here's my problem:
I have two files, one contains gene ids and a range indicted with start and stop positions: for example:

```
gene_id start stop 
grf4      1245  1365
fgt89     3089  4524
tig3      45600 46800
```

The other contains positions and information about those positions, for example:

```
position   nucleotide  %support
3980         T          98%
456          C          78%
45900        G          100%
4234         C          70%
```

I would like to generate a file that has a line for each gene_id and all the info from the second file that falls within that gene, for example:

```
gene_id  start  stop position nucleotide support
fgt89    3089    4524  3980    T         98%
fgt89    3089    4524  4234    C         70%
tig3     45600   46800 45900   G         100%
```

I am unsure the best way to do this, any suggestions are appreciated! The files are rather large, so speed is an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Change text into data

First I would suggest processing your files and saving them as database for easier further processing. You can extract data from these files eg. in the following ways:

```
file1 = open('some_filename.txt')
file1_lines = [filter(len, line.split(' ')) for line in file1.readlines()]
```

and the `file1_lines` will contain something similar to this:

> [['gene_id', 'start', 'stop'], ['grf4', '1245', '1365'], ['fgt89', '3089', '4524'], ['tig3', '45600', '46800']]

which means you have data you can now insert into the database.

### Insert data into the database

You should now insert the data into the database so it can be easily processed using proper tools (RDBMS in this case). I suggest using SQLite (see [sqlite3 built-in module for Python](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)). If you do not know SQL, ask specific questions about it. But I believe database is the form best suitable for your task.

### Extract data you need from the database

After you have your data in the database, it becomes easy to get data you want. The query could look like that (the query obviously has not been tested, but looks ok and should suit your needs if the names match names from your database):

```
SELECT `ranges`.`gene_id`, `ranges`.`start`, `ranges`.`stop`,
    `nucleotides`.`position`, `nucleotides`.`nucleotide`, `nucleotides`.`support`
FROM `ranges`
JOIN `nucleotides`
ON (
    (`ranges`.`start` < `nucleotides`.`position`)
    AND
    (`nucleotides`.`position` < `ranges`.`start`)
)
ORDER BY `ranges`.`gene_id` ASC, `nucleotides`.`position` ASC
```

Which will get you the data you wanted in the order of `gene_id` ascending, then `position` ascending.

The only task that will be left is outputting the data into the file. I suggest using [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) for that.

### Summary

So your task is basically consisting from the following parts:

1. Turn text (content of the files) into data (lists of variables).
2. Create database with proper structure.
3. Insert data from files into the database (make sure integers and floats are stored as such, not as strings).
4. Make a query to the database as I mentioned above.
5. If necessary, output the data into the file as text (using string formatting - `format()`).

Did it help? Do you have any questions?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know a database is the way to go, I'm trying to figure out how to use Riak to implement things the right way - I am just trying to figure out something quick to get some preliminary info for my boss. I'll see if I can use your idea to get things going quicker!

Comment: @user1084837: I believe this is the way to go. Instead of juggling with the proper lines from the files you have it is more comfortable to create SQLite database (`sqlite3` is a standard Python module, and there are lots of tutorials on how to use it) and use its mechanisms for processing the data. That way you will have the data and will be able to generate preliminary reports and even be more flexible if your boss requests some specific data (assuming you know SQL). The problem here may be a learning curve (SQL, Python, `sqlite3` module etc.), but you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Off course data base is the ideal solution as posted by Tadeck but here is what you can try

```
>>> def Test():
    fin1=open("file1.txt") #File as per your First Table
    fin2=open("file2.txt") #File as per your Second Table
    fin1.readline()        #Skip the Header
    fin2.readline()        #Skip the Header
    #Sort The First list and create an Iterator
    data1=iter(sorted([[f.split()[1],f.split()[2],f.split()[0]] 
               for f in fin1.xreadlines()], key=operator.itemgetter(0)))  
    #Sort The Second List and create an Iterator
    data2=iter(sorted([f.split() for f in fin2.xreadlines()],
               key=operator.itemgetter(0))) 
    #Print The Header
    print "{0:10}{1:10}{2:10}{3:10}{4:10}{5:10}".format("gene_id",
                                                        "start",
                                                        "stop",
                                                        "position",
                                                        "nucleotide",
                                                        "support") 
    try:
        v1=data1.next() #Read First Item from First List
        v2=data2.next() #Read Second Item from First List
        while True: #Loop Until One of the List has reached the end
            #If the Position is greater than stop range (from first list), 
            #read the next item from the first list
            if v2[0] > v1[1]: 
                 v1=data1.next() 
            #If the Position is greater or equal than the start range 
            #(We are in the range)
            elif v2[0] >= v1[0]: 
                #Format and Print it
                print "{0:10}{1:10}{2:10}{3:10}{4:10}{5:10}".format(v1[2],
                                                                    v1[0],
                                                                    v1[1],
                                                                    v2[0],
                                                                    v2[1],
                                                                    v2[2]) 
                #Read the Next Item From the Second List
                v2=data2.next() 
            #Not in any Range so Read the Next Item From the Second List
            else: v2=data2.next() 
    except StopIteration:
        None


>>> Test()
gene_id   start     stop      position  nucleotidesupport   
fgt89     3089      4524      3980      T         98%       
fgt89     3089      4524      4234      C         70%       
tig3      45600     46800     45900     G         100%      
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple Perl solution might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F2, '<', '8410347-file2.txt' or die $!;
my %at_position;
while (<$F2>) {
    my ($position, $nucleotide, $support) = split;
    warn "Duplicate position $position\n" if exists $at_position{$position};
    $at_position{$position} = {nucleotide => $nucleotide,
                               support    => $support};
}
close $F2;

open my $F1, '<', '8410347-file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$F1>) {
    my ($id, $start, $stop) = split;
    my @matches = grep $_ >= $start && $_ <= $stop, keys %at_position;
    for my $match (@matches) {
        print join("\t",
                   $id,
                   $start,
                   $stop,
                   $match,
                   $at_position{$match}{nucleotide},
                   $at_position{$match}{support},
                  ), "\n";
    }
}
```

If your files are large, this approach will be too slow and some more elaborate structure will be needed to capture the intervals (e.g. see [Lazy Manager's Calendar](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=908453)).